# How set feature by id via Data Hub CLI?

Tags: here-api

Could you please help me to find proper command in HERE CLI that to request of feature by id ?

I am trying it now, but it's return all features:

```
here xyz show MY_SPACE_ID --feature MY_SPACE_ID,MY_FEATURE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper command is:

```
here xyz show MY_SPACE_ID -s "f.id=MY_FEATURE_ID" -r
```